# Basic Tomcat Servlet error

Tags: tomcat, servlets

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req,
                     HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    out.println("Hello, world!");
    out.close();
  }
}
```

web.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Hello, World Application</display-name>
    <description>
    This is a simple web application with a source code organization
    based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
    </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>mypackage.Hello</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I am then doing ant all , ant reload and also /etc/init.d/tomcat restart

But I get this error on browser:

HTTP Status 404 - /hello/

type Status report

message /hello/

description The requested resource (/hello/) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.26

What could be wrong?

Comment: Sounds like your web-app is not deployed to tomcat. Does your tomcat have the manager servlet installed? That can help. Also, change your url-pattern in the servlet-mapping to just "/*".

Comment: I changed my web.xml , did ant all and then ant reload. Still my web.xml did not get copied to the tomcat webapps/hello/WEB-INF folder. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong with directory structure. Usally you do below directory structure

```
webapps
  MyWebApp1
  MyWebApp2
```

If your application is copied to `MyWebApp1` folder, then call `localhost/MyWebApp1/hello`

So the directory will be

```
webapps
  +MyWebApp1
    test.jsp
    WEB-INF
      web.xml
      +classes
        +mypackage
          hello.class
  +MyWebApp2
```

Comment: Look at the last comment of the OP. He says that he has a `webapps/hello/WEB-INF` folder. Now look closer at the 404 error message ... :) Yes, it's more likely simply the request URL which is wrong, not the project structure.

Comment: According to his directory structure he have to call 'localhost/hello/hello' one hello for directory name and one heloo for servlet mapping. he just calls localhost/hello tomcat searches for welcomefile did not find any welcome file and generates an error.